# Electron build failed

Tags: vue.js, webpack, electron, electron-builder, electron-vue

Electron build failed.

> Error: Cannot find module 'fs/promises' Require stack:
>
> - /Users/abhimatta/Documents/abhishek/accura-electron-dev/node_modules/builder-util/out/fs.js
> - /Users/abhimatta/Documents/abhishek/accura-electron-dev/node_modules/builder-util/out/util.js
> - /Users/abhimatta/Documents/abhishek/accura-electron-dev/node_modules/electron-builder/out/cli/cli.js
> - /Users/abhimatta/Documents/abhishek/accura-electron-dev/node_modules/electron-builder/cli.js
>   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797:15)
>   at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:27)
>   at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)
>   at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
>   at Object. (/Users/abhimatta/Documents/abhishek/accura-electron-dev/node_modules/builder-util/src/fs.ts:4:1)
>   at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
>   at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
>   at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
>   at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
>   at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)
>   at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
>   at Object. (/Users/abhimatta/Documents/abhishek/accura-electron-dev/node_modules/builder-util/src/util.ts:24:1)
>   at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
>   at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
>   at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
>   at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)

**Package.json configurations**

```
"electron": "^10.4.0",
"electron-builder": "^22.10.4",
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to node_modules folder. Find electron-updater. Go to out and AppUpdater.js then change

```
const promises_1 = require("fs/promises");
```

to

```
const promises_1 = require("fs").promises;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to learn Electron. Level - zero.

1. I would check your node and electron versions match.
   Info: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/electron-timelines
   My version -- node 12.22.7 -- electron 11.5.0
2. I eliminated this error while learning Electron in this way:
   if error: "cannot find module'fs/promises'
   then
   npm uninstall electron-builder
   and
   npm i electron-builder@22.10.5

The developers claim that this bug is indeed present in node 12
and is fixed in node 14+.